# Inaccurate matrix power in Java

Tags: java, android, matrix

I'm working on a calculator app for Android (in Java) with some basic matrix capabilities. I've tried two algorithms, SVD and eigenvalue decomposition, to implement matrix power, but the results are a little inaccurate for my taste. For example, `[[1,2];[3,4]]^2.3`returns as `[11.463254,16.618358];[24.927537,36.390583]]` in Scilab (after `abs` to removing the annoying imaginary parts), but my app gives `[[11.5107804,16.4911239];[26.2208761,37.1379804]]`. I'm taking Scilab's answer as truth, and WolframAlpha corroborates it.

The answer above (from my app) is using SVD. Eigenvalue decomp gives a "plain wrong" answer. Is there any way to improve the accuracy of the answer? I'm using [EJML](https://code.google.com/p/efficient-java-matrix-library/) for the matrix backend work, and my testing is on a Nexus 7 running Android 4.3. And no, as far as I can tell, EJML does not have its own matrix power/exponentiation method.

Answer (score 1):

The [la4j](http://la4j.org) (Linear Algebra for Java) does have a `power` operation for `Matrix` class since 0.4.5 version. But it can be used only with integer exponents. Like this:

```
// creates a new dense matrix
Matrix a = new Basic2DMatrix(...);

// performs 'a * a * a' in O(log n) via exponentiation-by-squaring
Matrix b = a.power(3);
```

Anyway, I'll think about supporting double exponents for `power` method.

Comment: Unfortunately, EJML is already pretty ingrained into the app so I'd rather not change it out. And I'd really like to support floating point powers in this app.